# Print statement under __len__ definition leads to constantly repeating console output

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I've used Python for years without dabbling in the art of classes very much, and decided it's time to get some insight on the topic. I thus decided to play around with them a bit, and was in particular playing around with the dunder functionality. I made the following class:

```
class TestClass:
    
    def __init__(self,y):
        self.x = [1,2,3]
        self.y = y
    
    def __len__(self):
        print('gottem')
        return len(self.x)
    
    def __str__(self):
        print('gottem again')
        return str(self.y)
```

Once I instantiate the class within the console, all subsequent console statements are concatenated with 'gottem', see console snippet below:

```
>>> 1+1
Out[2]: 2

>>> a = TestClass(3)
gottem

>>> 2+2
Out[4]: 4gottem

>>> len(a)
gottem
Out[5]: 3gottem
```

I've tried removing the `__len__` definition, but I observe no similar behaviour with the `__str__` definition, which indeed seems to function as I would expect. The behaviour goes away once I redefine `a`, so that the class instantiation is dropped. I am completely stumped as to what causes this behaviour, and why it only happens for `__len__`. Is there an obvious explanation behind this?

Info: I am running Anaconda's Python 3.7.6 distribution through Spyder.

Disclaimer: I absolutely tried to search for some information on this, but I either have no clue what to search for, or alternatively am doing something so fundamentally wrong that the questions don't even exist.

Comment: Your class works as you would expect, with "gottem" only printing when invoking `len` on an instance of your class. Tested with IDLE Python 3.8.2.

Comment: Interestingly I get similar behavior using the Python Console in Pycharm. Only difference is that `gottem again` is printed with every command

Comment: It would indeed appear as though this is some bug that pertains to the use of certain IDE's, and perhaps only certain distributions. When running both Python 3.7.6 AND 3.8.5 through cmd, I had no issues. I wanted to try running this with 3.8.5 through Spyder as well, but I'm afraid I do not have time to set it up.